# How to use global variable ${__from} and ${__to} in Filter data by values

Tags: json, charts, grafana

I want to display a Pie Chart based on the date range selected by the user. I converted my source date into a timestamp to simplify the process, but when trying to use the global variable as indicated in the documentation, the filter does not accept it.

0. The query (JSON API) :
   [image: Query]
1. Convert date in timestamp
   [image: Convert date as number]
2. Trying to use the global variable in the filter
   [image: Global variable use in the filter]

Documentation read:

- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/variables/add-template-variables/#__from-and-__to
- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/visualizations/pie-chart/
- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/?utm_source=grafana#use-a-dashboard-variable

I already try `{__from}` and `__from`, its like the input accept Number only but I want to use the date range given by the dashboard.

Comment: AFAIK, Grafana still doesn't support variables in Transformations. Certainly was true for 10 on release, and I doubt that changed

Comment: https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/25469

Comment: Thanks for your help @markalex but did you know another way to do it  ?

Comment: The only way I know is to pass those as parameters into your data source. But but your backend needs to support/implement such filtering. Otherwise, I don't think it's possible to do what you want.